# Symfony 2 Validate Proxy Entity

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, proxy

So I have an entity with annotation asserts and I call validate() manually on the entity, everything works as expected.

However sometimes a process before this hydrates the same entity through a relationship. Then later when I fetch the entity normally I get a proxy of that entity (which is initialised), I believe Doctrine does this automatically for performance reasons.

However when I then come to validate it, because the class is a proxy the annotation asserts don't get picked up.

Should validate() know how to validate a proxy by loading the asserts from it's base class it proxies from? I assume not since it isn't.

So my question is, is there any way to turn a proxy entity into it's normal entity class (I don't mean hydrate/initialise it because it already is).

Or is there a way to force Doctrine to re-fetch the entity from the database and not return me an initialised proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-ha I had to call `$em->clear()` after requesting the related entity to make sure I got a none-proxy entity the next time round.