# "Default" validation group not transformed into group sequence in embedded entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have the following form type:

```
class ProjectStep1Type extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('client', new ClientType(), [
            'label' => 'Client',
        ]);

        // More fields

        // Save as draft button
        $builder->add('saveDraft', 'submit', [
            'label' => 'Save as draft',
        ]);
        // Actual submit button
        $builder->add('validate', 'submit', [
            'label' => 'Validate',
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $validationGroups = function(FormInterface $form) {
            if ($form->get('saveDraft')->isClicked()) {

                return ['Default', 'Draft'];
            }

            return ['Default', 'Step1'];
        };

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'        => 'AppBundle\Entity\Project',
            'validation_groups' => $validationGroups,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The (partial) validation yaml file looks like this:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Client:
    group_sequence:
        - Client
        - TypesOK
    properties:
        label:
            - NotNull:
                groups: [Step1]
            - Type: string
            - Length:
                max: 255
                groups: [TypesOK]
        vatCode:
            - NotNull:
                groups: [Step1]
            - Type:
                type: string
        contact:
            - NotNull: ~
            - Type: AppBundle\Entity\Contact
            - Valid: ~
        address:
            - Type: AppBundle\Entity\Address
            - Valid: ~
        sector:
            - NotNull:
                groups: [Step1]
            - Type: AppBundle\Entity\CompanySector

AppBundle\Entity\Project:
    group_sequence:
        - Project
        - TypesOK
    properties:
        client:
            - NotNull:
                message: form.project.client.error.not_null
            - Type: AppBundle\Entity\Client
            - Valid: ~
        status:
            - NotNull: ~
            - Type: string
            - Choice:
                choices: [DRAFT_1, DRAFT_2, DRAFT_3, SENT, REJECTED, DELETED]
                groups: [TypesOK]
```

Now on to the problem: When I validate the form, the `Project` entity is correctly validated, once for each group in the sequence, i.e. `[Project, TypesOK, Draft]`.

The `Client` entity, however, is validated using the `Default` validation group. If the validation succeeds with `Default`, the groups `Client` and `TypesOK` are not called.

If the validation fails however, these groups are called! And error messages I would rather not have at this point are displayed along with the errors raised when validated with `Default`.

What I expected is that `Client` is never validated using `Default`, but that, instead, the `Default` group be converted to the group sequence `[Client, TypesOK]`, even if it goes through the `Valid` constraint.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I made some progression about this. The validation problem I have only happens when I edit the form. When I edit the form, a Proxy class inheriting `Client` is used instead of the regular `Client` class.

A normal feature for Doctrine.

However, the validator metadata factory does not use the group sequence of the parent `Client`. It fetches its constraints, but not this property.

It seems this problem is quite close to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008760/symfony-2-validate-proxy-entity) however the resolution in there do not work for me.

The problem seems pretty clear for me now, however I have no idea about how I should solve this properly.

Comment: Same problem over here. We have an `OrderLine` type, and want to add it to a formBuilder in a specific workflow. The validation works okay if we use the `OrderLine` type separately, but the validation always kicks in if used via another form.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I saw was that in your validation group for `AppBundle\Entity\Project` client is defined as `ItalyBundle\Entity\Client` but in the validation group for the client `AppBundle\Entity\Client` is being used.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's only a copy/paste error on my part. Fixed it.